# Php, number of occurrences in a string

Tags: php, string, char

I'm looking for a way to count the number of occurrences in a string, I find 2 php function to do this:

1. [substr_count](https://www.php.net/substr_count)
2. [count_chars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)

I try to understand what is the difference between this 2 functions.

The major difference i saw is that `substr_count` is case sensitive, But i didn't understand about `count_chars` the following statement:

> Counts the number of occurrences of every byte-value (0..255) in string and returns it in various ways.

If anyone can please explain the major differences between this 2 functions, Maybe some example can help.

Comment: Examples for both functions are in the manual, and the description is pretty clear as well IMHO.

Comment: I try to understand the manual, Can you please be more descriptive.

Comment: Not unless you explain better what exactly you are having trouble understanding with.

Comment: Before asking you should read the manual. You only ask a specific question when you need info.

Comment: You did not, if you did you would have seen the Examples listed there. Not sure how more explaining is possible when there are examples. If you had a hard time understanding the manual, there is no possible answer anyone can give you which will make you understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `count_chars()` counts the number of occurrences of **every byte value**, whereas `substr_count()` will count the number of occurrences of a **particular substring**.
- `substr_count()` can be used to search for the number of occurrences of a substring inside a selective region of the string, which is not possible with `count_chars()`.
- `count_chars()` returns an array / string depending on the argument, but `substr_count()` will always return an integer.

Answer (score 0):

`substr_count`counts the occurences of a given string in another string; while `count_chars`counts the occurences of every single character in the given string